# Why is this grep command not excluding images?

Tags: regex, grep

My regex has been tested (using online checkers) and is working.  I'm attempting to get http links from a file but specifically **excluding** http links ending with an image extension (jpg, gif) using this;

```
 grep -Eo '(http|https|rtmp)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*' | grep -v '.(?:jpg|gif|png)'
```

This is my file which grep is working on;

```
LONDON Remote server cluster 88: taken, https://www.wiredcontent/rashida_opener_background2.jpg
http://www.8379f690ba57e0fdf8f944324a4453de67780/tsa.a3m

BRUSSELS: Hosted MPLS cluster
http://www.5b0e9bc72b989c87a9a70da7865dbb5b4aa9c086/tsa.a3m

PARIS: Hosted atrium access, https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/dell_UP3218K_1483646315000.gif
http://www.39415215319c9brt6b9c7d10238c19cc82e7f88b/tsa.a3m

PRAGUE: Main Office access, 
http://www.e721f751ab0936706192cf15b4632889b38f131a/tsa.a3m
```

I want grep to return this:

```
http://www.8379f690ba57e0fdf8f944324a4453de67780/tsa.a3m
http://www.5b0e9bc72b989c87a9a70da7865dbb5b4aa9c086/tsa.a3m
http://www.39415215319c9brt6b9c7d10238c19cc82e7f88b/tsa.a3m
http://www.e721f751ab0936706192cf15b4632889b38f131a/tsa.a3m
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: Vatsug answer below is very helpful and does work with a file.txt with the links in, but if the links are being piped in from a variable within a script I ended up having to do something like this: `link=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*' | grep -vP '(http|https|rtmp)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*(jpg|png|gif)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-P` flag for Perl extension in the second `grep` call worked for me:

```
echo "$input" | grep -Eo '(http|https|rtmp)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*'  | grep -vP '.(?:jpg|gif|png)'
```

This requires that your `grep` supports the Perl-extension.

Comment: Ok, with example input.txt your solution works, thanks for this but I have a different issue, I should've explained that the I'm piping in the value for grep to work on like this: `LINK=echo "$line" | grep -Eo '(http|https|rtmp)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*' | grep -vP '.(?:jpg|gif|png)'`
and unfortunately  your solution didn't work in this circumstance.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I think its because my $line variable is actually a line which is piped in from the command just before my grep command; `| while read line; do` I think your solution works because the grep is working on a whole text file and my grep is working within a bash script on a single line from original file - I hope I make sense!

Comment: I don't think I understand fully. I think you should edit your question to give more context and detail.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with this code: ` link=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*' | grep -vP '(http|https|rtmp)://[a-zA-Z0-9:0-9./?=_@&%|()[:blank:],;-]*(jpg|png|gif)')`  Thanks for your help